# What should I do when I want to marry a man but none of my relatives will be wali?

Tags: nikah, wali

I have tried all possible means to get my dad to accept the man I want to marry, but he keeps on saying no simply because of some cultural belief. The man I want to marry is a Muslim and religious, but from the look of things none of my family member is ready to stand as my wali. So what should I do?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam the Q&A site about Islam. TO learn more about our site's model and policies I strongly recommend you to take our 2 min. [tour] and visit our [help] and for further information our [meta].

Answer (score -1):

I would say, try hard to convince your dad.

Show him the quality of this man, his characteristics, The voluntary work that he does, is he Hafiz for example, how he always takes care of his parents, and etc.

Try also to convince your mom, and ask her to convince dad.

If nothing helped, I would say, obey them. If you obey your parents, Allah will get you something even better InshaAllah.

Answer (score -1):

786  I know you have heard this before, and I apologize for that, but I have to add since it works wonders: All success is with God (swt).  Make du'a, and most especially make abundant salawat/durood on the Prophet (sawa).

Comment: What does 786 mean!?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. Please consider taking your time to give a full answer (see [answer]) and I strongly suggest you to get informed and learn more about our site and the stack exchange model by taking our 2 min. [tour] and checking our [help].